# search for string in array of structs C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct

I am trying to create a function that allows me to type a name and return that employees information found in the struct. /.......................................................................

```
// info (ss_number,etc..)    
struct employees { 
    int ss_number;
    int dob; //date of birth
    string f_name;
    string l_name;
    string state;
};
void print_person(employees e)
{
cout<<e.ss_number<<" "<<e.dob<<" "e.f_name<<" "<<e.l_name<<" "<<e.state;
}
void search(employees array[])
{
    string first;
    string last;
    cout << "Enter name"; //Example Jack Patton
    cin >> first >> last;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if(array[i].f_name == first && array[i].l_name == last) {
            print_person(array[i]);
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    employees array[10];
    search(array);
}
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: My bad, i'm using c++

Comment: What's happening? (I.e. what problem does your code have?) You didn't ask a question!

Comment: sorry, new to this. when i enter in a name nothing shows up. how do i get the ss_number, dob, etc for whomevers name i type in?

Comment: You don't initialize any values for your `employees array[10]` inside `main()`, so you won't find anybody.

Comment: You never initialize your employees.

Answer (score 0):

This requires C++11 and fulfills your requirements.  Notice I switched to vector (since you're using string you are using C++), and am using a built in algorithm with a lambda.  C++ has a lot of built in functionality in the standard libraries to make this sort of thing much easier.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Employee
{
    int socialSecurtyNumber;
    int yearOfBirth;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string state;
};

vector<Employee>::iterator search(vector<Employee> &employees, const string &first, const string &last)
{
    return find_if(begin(employees), end(employees), [&](const Employee& employee){
        return employee.firstName == first && employee.lastName == last;
    });
}
int main()
{
    vector<Employee> employees{
        { 100, 1985, "John", "Edwards", "AB" },
        { 101, 1960, "Mike", "Thomas", "CA" },
        { 102, 1992, "George", "Flunky", "FL" },
        { 103, 1983, "Tweet", "Johnson", "AB" },
        { 104, 1968, "Michael", "Jordan", "OH" },
    };
    string first;
    string last;
    cout << "Enter name: "; //Example Jack Patton
    cin >> first >> last;
    auto employee = search(employees, first, last);
    if (employee != end(employees)){
        cout << "FOUND! SSN: " << employee->socialSecurtyNumber << " YOB: " << employee->yearOfBirth << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "NOT FOUND!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Prefer returning iterators instead of naked pointers to internal data of the vector

Comment: Should be `int main()`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks, I copied the user's code and didn't notice.

Comment: I had someone try to edit in a "return" at the end of main.  This is unnecessary.  http://zamanbakshifirst.blogspot.ca/2006/11/c-c-main-should-return-void.html Relevant part: "If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;"

Answer (score 0):

*t is better to place the request for the name outside the function. The function should do only the search.

It could be defined the following way

```
const employee * search( const employees array[], size_t n, 
                   const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &name )
{
    const employees *first = array;     

    while ( first != array + n && 
            !( first->f_name == name.first && first->l_name == name.second ) )
    {
        ++first;
    }

    return first;
}
```

And in main it could be called the following way (take into account that main shall have return type int):

```
int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    employees array[N];

    // filling the array

    std::pair<std::string, std::string> name;

    cout << "Enter name"; //Example Jack Patton
    cin >> name.first >> name.second;

    const employees *emp = search( array, N, name );

    if ( emp != array + N )
    {
        print_person( *emp );
    }

    //...
}
```

Or you could use standard algorithm `std::find_if` with a predicate.

At the same time function print_person should be defined as

```
void print_person( const employees &e)
{
cout<<e.ss_number<<" "<<e.dob<<" "e.f_name<<" "<<e.l_name<<" "<<e.state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is mostly fine except that you never initialized any values for your array.

You could read them in from a file, but in the meantime write this and it will work (thanks M2tM for the data):

```
employees array[10] = 
{   { 100, 1985, "John", "Edwards", "AB" }
,   { 101, 1960, "Mike", "Thomas", "CA" }
/* fill in more rows if you want */
};
```

Other issues: in  `print_person` you are missing an `<<` before `e.f_name`  ; and `void main()` should be `int main()`.